# Unable to hide site column from the New form using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I want to hide a site column from the New form, so i tried this PnP script:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/" -UseWebLogin           
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ctx = Get-PnPContext
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $field = Get-PnPField -Identity "ProjectDepartment"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $field.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The node to be inserted is from a different document context."
At line:1 char:1
+ $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

so i am not sure why i am getting the above error? altohugh i have a site column with internal name = "ProjectDepartment"!!?
any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script instead:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/" -UseWebLogin

$fieldTitle = "ProjectDepartment"
$field = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle)
$field.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$field.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Reference: [SharePoint CSOM and “The node to be inserted is from a different document context.”.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/sharepoint-csom-and-the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context/)